# How can I initialize my dynamic array with braces, like a standard vector or array?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, overloading

I have a class that defines an array like this:

```
template <class T>
class DynamicArray {
private:
    T* _a;
    int _len;
    int _max;
public:
    ....
}
```

How can I initialize it like I do with vectors:

```
vector<int> a={1, 2, 3, 4}; //(transfer {int, int ,int,...} into an array)
```

I want my DynamicArray to be able to do the same thing, assuming I've got all the functions and operators I need:

```
DynamicArray<int> a={1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Comment: Add a constructor with a `std::initializer_list<T>` parameter.

Comment: Give your `DynamicArray` a constructor that accepts an initialiser list.   Plenty of examples are online, to be found with your favourite search engine.